# How to move line to specific position in a file using python

Tags: python, file

I want to loop over the contents of a xml file and do a search for lines with tags `<testcase id=` and then move it before the tags `<title>`.
After that write the result back to the file.
So the file should have this structure:

```
<testcases> 
   <testcase> 
     <title> ... </title> 
     <initialstate> ... </initialstate>
   </testcase> 
</testcases>
```

the xml file looks like this:

```html
<testcases xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../_formats/testcases.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<title>Configuration files and software are valid</title>
<initialstate>operational mode is OK</initialstate>
<technique> func</technique>
<interfaces>14</interfaces>
<requirement></requirement>
<status>draft</status>
<release> CS1.0</release>
<description> main success scenario tests the startup of SD with valid configuration files and software.</description>
<testcase id="TEST-SYSINT-CFG001">
<step>
<action>
- connect SD to network</action>
<expectedreaction>check that SD received config file successful</expectedreaction>
</step>
</testcase>
<title>Some configuration files are invalid and software valid      </title>
<initialstate>operational mode is OK</initialstate>
<technique> func</technique>
<interfaces>14</interfaces>
<requirement></requirement>
<status>draft</status>
<release> CS1.0</release>
<description> tests the startup of SD with some invalid configuration files while the software is valid.</description>
<testcase id="TEST-SYSINT-CFG002">
<step>
<action>
- connect SD to network</action>
<expectedreaction>check that SD received config file successful</expectedreaction>
</step>
</testcase>
</testcases>
```

Here is the code I tried so far:

```js
def reorder():   
    rfile = open(r"C:\Users\Z0042VZJ\Desktop\rf_parser\output.xml","r+")
    lines = rfile.readlines()
    search_line = "<testcase "
    lookup = "<title>"

    for line in lines:
        if search_line in line:
            line_num = [line]
            index = lines.index(line_num[0])
            print(index)
        if lookup in line:
            title_line = [line]
            title_index = lines.index(title_line[0])
            print(title_index)
            rfile.seek(0)
            lines.insert(title_index - 1, '\n')
            rf.write(line_num)

    rfile.close()
```